# How to restore a website offline. using XCloner on Joomla thats run on Xampp

Tags: joomla, xampp, offline, restore

I am totally new to this stuff. I have installed Joomla on my windows pc to test my changes to the site before I try them on the actual site and mess things up. 
I was given a backup using XCLONER. I installed xcloner but cant seem to restore the website. 
I am using XAMPP. 
I am also unsure where to place the directory where the restore file should be.
Any help will help. Any tutorials on this? again, just starting out with this stuff. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many references and tutorials out there:
[Google](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=move%20joomla%20site%20from%20server%20to%20localhost&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) 
 
Also Joomla.org has adequate [documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/Copying_a_Joomla_website) for this.

I can't say exactly about how the XCloner works, but the general steps to replicate Joomla is:

1. Copy and place the files and folders at the new location
2. Download the database
3. Create a new database at the new host (your computer) and import the data from the one you downloaded.
4. Configure Joomla (configuration.php) to connect to the new local database (host,user, password, prefix -if changed).
5. At this point you should be able to run your site to the new location, but you probably want to change also the path for logs and tmp folders, to reflect the new location.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have somehow figured it out!! as you said, many resources!