# Errors after moving Joomla! website to live server from localhost

Tags: php, joomla

I've got a Joomla! 2.5 website on my localhost and it's working fine. I need to move it to a live server so I've followed some tutorials on the Internet to make sure everything's fine so I did it like that:

1. export database from localhost to .sql file
2. install clean Joomla! 2.5 on server
3. move all the files and folder from localhost to server (except configuration.php)
4. deleted all tables from server's database and imported database from localhost

After these steps site doesn't load at all giving this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /home/users/zsrkm/public_html/templates/beez_20/error.php on line 10
```

http://www.zsrkm.pl/

When you enter http://www.zsrkm.pl/administrator there are even more errors. 
I'm very grateful for any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess it's path/requires/autoloading problem

Comment: What does it mean? How can I solve it?

Comment: this is a very commonly asked question. With a little search you will be able to find how to move your website. But I don't find the clean installation to the live server the appropriate way. Similar question I recently replied here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21247693/how-to-restore-a-website-offline-using-xcloner-on-joomla-thats-run-on-xampp/21264776#21264776

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to move a Joomla website is Akeeba Backup and Akeeba Kickstart.

Akeeba Backup backs up the database and the files into one file which makes it easier to move. Once you have created the database on the target server, upload `kickstart.php` and the backup file and then run `kickstart.php` to recreate the website.